# How to make CakePHP redirect to a different action/controller?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, cakephp

My situation:

The user is presented with a table or list of items. Beside each item they can click a checkbox to select it, and then at the bottom is a select box which says "With selected items...", and things like "delete", "move to project", "download", etc. You know the deal - bulk operations. Some of the operations will execute immediately and don't require their own view, however others will need an intermediate view (eg: "Move these to which project?").

Since each of the individual operations is handled by a different action (and different controller, possibly), but forms can only post to one address, I need an action which will take the posted data and dispatch it to the appropriate place.

Using `redirect()` will not work either, since this will need to be AJAX'd in the near future.

Basically I just want an action which will delegate to a different controller/action as if that were the original request: maintaining post data, rendering that view, etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to figure it out using the Dispatcher.

```
// for example, to reroute to users/delete

// this is in the controller which receives the request.
// this could even be in the AppController

$this->autoRender = false;
$d = new Dispatcher();
$d->dispatch(
    array("controller" => "users", "action" => "delete"),
    array("data" => $this->data)
);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you follow MVC design pattern, you'll have no problem with that, since the business logic should be in the Models, not the Controller actions.

Anyway, you can create a "bulk" action wich will call all the others searching for some data to work with.

Comment: yep - how do I do that? How do I call a different action on a different controller?

Comment: "call", per say, isn't very recommended. But you can instantiate the desired controllers inside the first one. Still, the best option is to have Models doing that work, and having a single controller action bulk(), for example. Things will be much more easy to handle when you port to ajax, btw